# Annotate text in ggplot2 plot ,included in a shiny app, does not work when I use fileInput to insert my dataset

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, subset, annotate

Below I have a fine working example with iris dataset. As you can see the annotated text is updated and displayed inside the plot everytime I change the variables. The problem is that my actual dataset comes from a csv file which I need to insert every time using `reactive()`. Then text annotation is not displayed at all,while everything else is still working. I assume that the problem lies in subsetting. In the working example I use :

```
output$an<-renderUI({

    radioButtons("an", label = h4("Correlation Coefficient"),
                 choices = list("Add Cor.Coef" = cor(subset(iris, select=c(input$lx1)),subset(iris, select=c(input$lx2))), "Remove Cor.Coef" = ""), 
                 selected = "")
  })
```

but my actual code is:

```
output$an<-renderUI({

    radioButtons("an", label = h4("Correlation Coefficient"),
                 choices = list("Add Cor.Coef" = cor(subset(rt(), select=c(input$lx1)),subset(rt(), select=c(input$lx2))), "Remove Cor.Coef" = ""), 
                 selected = "")
  })
```

Any thoughts?Or maybe alternatives instead of `annotate()`?

```
#ui.r
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
library(extrafont)

fluidPage(

  # App title ----
  titlePanel(div("CROSS CORRELATION",style = "color:blue")),

  # Sidebar layout with input and output definitions ----
  sidebarLayout(

    # Sidebar panel for inputs ----
    sidebarPanel(

      # Input: Select a file ----
      fileInput("file1", "Input CSV-File",
                multiple = TRUE,
                accept = c("text/csv",
                           "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                           ".csv")),

      # Horizontal line ----
      tags$hr(),

      # Input: Checkbox if file has header ----
      checkboxInput("header", "Header", TRUE),

      # Input: Select separator ----
      radioButtons("sep", "Separator",
                   choices = c(Comma = ",",
                               Semicolon = ";",
                               Tab = "\t"),
                   selected = ","),


      # Horizontal line ----
      tags$hr(),

      # Input: Select number of rows to display ----
      radioButtons("disp", "Display",
                   choices = c(Head = "head",
                               All = "all"),
                   selected = "head")





    ),
    # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
    mainPanel(

      tabsetPanel(type = "tabs",
                  tabPanel("Table",
                           shiny::dataTableOutput("contents")),
                  tabPanel("Correlation Plot",
                           tags$style(type="text/css", "
           #loadmessage {
                                      position: fixed;
                                      top: 0px;
                                      left: 0px;
                                      width: 100%;
                                      padding: 5px 0px 5px 0px;
                                      text-align: center;
                                      font-weight: bold;
                                      font-size: 100%;
                                      color: #000000;
                                      background-color: #CCFF66;
                                      z-index: 105;
                                      }
                                      "),conditionalPanel(condition="$('html').hasClass('shiny-busy')",
                                                          tags$div("Loading...",id="loadmessage")
                                      ),
                           fluidRow(
                             column(3, uiOutput("lx1")),
                           column(3,uiOutput("lx2"))),
                           hr(),
                           fluidRow(
                             tags$style(type="text/css",
                                        ".shiny-output-error { visibility: hidden; }",
                                        ".shiny-output-error:before { visibility: hidden; }"
                             ),
                           column(3,uiOutput("td")),
                           column(3,uiOutput("an"))),
                           plotlyOutput("sc"))
      ))
  ))
#server.r
function(input, output) {
  rt<-reactive({
    req(input$file1)

    csvdata <- read.csv(input$file1$datapath,
                        header = input$header
    )
    if(input$disp == "head"){
      head(csvdata)
    } else{
      csvdata
    } 


    csvdata
  }) 

  output$contents <- shiny::renderDataTable({

    iris
  })


  output$lx1<-renderUI({
    selectInput("lx1", label = h4("Select 1st Expression Profile"), 
                choices = colnames(iris[,1:4]), 
                selected = "Lex1")
  })
  output$lx2<-renderUI({
    selectInput("lx2", label = h4("Select 2nd Expression Profile"), 
                choices = colnames(iris[,1:4]), 
                selected = "Lex2")
  })

  output$td<-renderUI({
    radioButtons("td", label = h4("Trendline"),
                 choices = list("Add Trendline" = "lm", "Remove Trendline" = ""), 
                 selected = "")
  })

  output$an<-renderUI({

    radioButtons("an", label = h4("Correlation Coefficient"),
                 choices = list("Add Cor.Coef" = cor(subset(iris, select=c(input$lx1)),subset(iris, select=c(input$lx2))), "Remove Cor.Coef" = ""), 
                 selected = "")
  })   


 output$sc<-renderPlotly({

   p1 <- ggplot(iris, aes_string(x = input$lx1, y = input$lx2))+
     # Change the point options in geom_point
     geom_point(color = "darkblue") +
     # Change the title of the plot (can change axis titles
     # in this option as well and add subtitle)
     labs(title = "Cross Correlation") +
     # Change where the tick marks are
     scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 30, 2.5)) +

     # Change how the text looks for each element
     theme(title = element_text(family = "Calibri", 
                                size = 10, 
                                face = "bold"), 
           axis.title = element_text(family = "Calibri Light", 
                                     size = 16, 
                                     face = "bold", 
                                     color = "darkgrey"), 
           axis.text = element_text(family = "Calibri", 
                                    size = 11))+
     theme_bw()+
     geom_smooth(method = input$td)+
     annotate("text", x = 5, y = 5, label = as.character(input$an))
   ggplotly(p1) %>%
     layout(hoverlabel = list(bgcolor = "white", 
                              font = list(family = "Calibri", 
                                          size = 9, 
                                          color = "black")))

 }) 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually the problem was different my dataset included NAs which I replaced with

```
x <- c(1,2,NA,4,5)
x[is.na(x)] <- 0
```

I leave the question as it may help others.